# How to implement Findset operation on Disjointset for key, value pairs from a vector; where key is an int and value is a string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

**to represent disjoint set**

```
class DisjointSet {
          unordered_map<int, string> parent;
          public:
```

**perform makeset operation**

```
void makeSet(vector<pair<int,string>> &vect) 
{ 
          for (const pair<int, string> &vect : vect)
          { // create n disjoint sets
          parent[vect.first] = vect.first; 
          }
}
```

**Find the root of the set in which pair k,v belongs**

```
int Find(int &k, string &v) 
{ 
          if (parent[k,v] == pair(k,v)) // if k,v is root
          return pair(k,v);
          return Find(parent[pair(k,v)]); **recurs for parent till we find root**
}


int main ()
{
    DisjointSet dis;
    int key;
    string value;
    vector<pair<int,string>> vect; **vect contains key,value pairs ​​read from a file (already solved!!)**



int k1,k2;
string v1,v2;
cout<<"enter 2 pairs key/value!"<<endl;
cout<<"first pair:"<<endl<<"enter key"<<endl;
cin>>k1;
cout<<"value"<<endl;
cin>>v1;
cout<<"Second pair:"<<endl<<"enter key"<<endl;
cin>>k2;
cout<<"value"<<endl;
cin>>v2;
```

**if they are belong to same set or not.**

```
if (dis.Find(k1,v1) == dis.Find(k2,v2)) 
        cout<<"same set"<<endl;
else
        cout<<"Not";
}
```

**what are the problems and how can i solve them ?? I don't know how to handle key,value pairs**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).